# How to use flutter font awesome icons?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have import dependencies called `flutter_font_awesome` updated version from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter)

but unfortunately when I tried then does not show any icon.

I have tried like this way:

```
dependencies:
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.1.0
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
```

```
  Expanded(
                child: ReusableCard(
                  color: activeCardColor,
                  cardChild: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      // Icon(
                      //   FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
                      //   size: 80.0,
                      // ),
                      IconButton(
                          // Use the FaIcon Widget + FontAwesomeIcons class for the IconData
                          icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.mars),
                          onPressed: () {
                            print("Pressed");
                          }),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 15.0,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'MALE',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          color: Color(0xFF8D8E98),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

I have stop and restarted the code already but still the same problem.

Any suggestion please.

Comment: Your code is correct. what is the error? and code is working on My machine **IconButton(
                  // Use the FaIcon Widget + FontAwesomeIcons class for the IconData
                  icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.mars),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print("Pressed");
                  }),**

Comment: Thanks, I was a mistake when passing the props, now I have solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 flutter clean
```

after this

```
flutter pub get
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ayush Rawat. but it does not work